# Conditionally Hide fields from Content Editor

Tags: sxa

In one of my projects in `Sitecore 10.2`, I am using one base template in other child templates. My requirement is that I want to hide some base template fields in some child templates.
For that, I am referring

https://andrey-vinda.tech.blog/2017/10/30/sitecore-hide-fields-from-content-editor/.

In the above example, we have to inherit `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields`

But I am not able to access it.
Any idea how we can get this namespace in `Sitecore 10.2` Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Sitecore.Client` dll reference in your project, after that you will be able to access `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields`
Below is the pipeline processor for this

````
 <processor type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.
 GetContentEditorFields.GetFields, Sitecore.Client" >
 </processor>
 </getContentEditorFields>```
````

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After extracting the DLL `Sitecore.Client`, I found that it exists in the same DLL. Please refer the screenshot.

[image]

And the namespace is also the same. So you have to use this DLL to access the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields`

```
namespace Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields
{
  /// <summary>Implements the Render Field pipeline.</summary>
  public class GetFields
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields" /> shows the data fields only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.GetContentEditorFields.GetFields" /> shows the data fields only; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool ShowDataFieldsOnly { get; private set; }
```